# Why is std::abs(9484282305798401ull) = 9484282305798400?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, precision, c++17

I'm currently writing a templated helper method that can convert C numbers in general (including unsigned long long) to mpz_class numbers in the GMP library. In between, there is a call to `std::abs`.

However, it turns out that for on C++17 (g++ 6.3.1),

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (unsigned long long)std::abs(9484282305798401ull);
}
```

gives an incorrect output of `9484282305798400`.

As I understood from [cmath](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/), `std::abs` first casts the argument into a double.

According to the C++ docs, double has 52 mantissa bits, which means that the maximum integer value that I must be strictly less than `2^52 = 4503599627370496` before any loss of precision.

Am I correct to say that since `9484282305798401` exceeds this limit, `std::abs` ends up discarding precision to give an incorrect answer?

To clarify, I'm absolutely aware that it makes completely no sense to ask for the absolute value of an unsigned integer; However, I would like the templated function work for general C numbers, instead of having to specifically create a specialization for each signed and unsigned type separately.

Comment: If I may, whats the point of calling `abs` on an unsigned type?

Comment: I'm writing a templated function that goes through some arithmetic before calling the mpz_import class of the GMP library; In between there is a call to std::abs that may be required for signed numbers.

Comment: Related to [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801)

Comment: Note that whilst IEEE 754 double precision does use 52 bits to store the mantissa, there are effectively 53 bits since the value is normalized and there is an 'implicit 1' (see this SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930269/floating-point-the-leading-1-is-implicit-in-the-significand-huh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, what you are doing doesn't really make sense out of context (getting the absolute value of an unsigned type). But I digress.

The code you have posted doesn't compile. At least not in the compiler I used (whichever one repl.it uses). Instead it complains of an ambiguous overload. Even if it did compile, it would cast the `unsigned long long` to a different type which cannot support its actual value (in this case `double`).

Changing `abs` to `llabs` like so:

```
std::cout << (unsigned long long)std::llabs(9484282305798401ull);
```

..both makes it compile and produces an accurate result. See the documentation of the different `abs` functions for integer types [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs).

Comment: Older versions of [libstdc++ used to accept this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287410/why-is-stdabs9484282305798401ull-9484282305798400#comment75586599_44287410) I suspect it will be a while before those older versions mostly go away.

Comment: True, however OP stated that they are using c++17, and the error is present from c++11. But for completeness' sake I will include this in my answer.

Comment: [gcc 6.3 using c++1z and -pedantic](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dLCav79n8E2li63Q) no diagnostic.

Comment: Slight problem w/ using `llabs` is that `The behavior is undefined if the result cannot be represented by the return type`

Answer (score 9):

Your program is ill-formed. From [[c.math.abs]/29.9.2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math.abs#3):

> If `abs()` is called with an argument of type `X` for which `is_­unsigned_­v<X>` is `true` and if `X` cannot be converted to `int` by integral promotion, the program is ill-formed.

Compilers should have to warn you about this though.

It also doesn't really make sense to call `std::abs` on an unsigned type anyways.

Comment: Ill-formed requires a diagnostic, see [details in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685448/1708801) it does not have to be an error though. UB and ill-formed NDR on the other hand do not require a diagnostic

Comment: This is one of the neat things about UB and constexpr, [UB is ill-formed in a constexpr and therefore requires a diagnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413/1708801).

Comment: @Shafik Yes, you're totally right. I misread the explanation of ill-formed :)

Comment: It has total sense to cast `std::abs` on an unsigned type when you're dealing with templates. In that case, it should just be an identity function.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own overload of `abs` if you want to manage unsigned types in a way that is different for what the standard library function does:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>

namespace my {

template <class S>
auto abs (S x) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<S>::value,
                                          decltype(std::abs(x))>::type
{
    return std::abs(x);
}

template <class U>
auto abs (U x) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, U>::type
{
    return x;
}

} // namespace my
```

Then

```
std::cout << my::abs(9484282305798401ull) << '\n'              // -> 9484282305798401
          << my::abs(-3.14159) << '\n'                         // -> 3.14159
          << my::abs(std::numeric_limits<char>::min()) << '\n' // -> 128
          << my::abs(std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) << '\n'  // -> -2147483648
```

Please, note that `std::abs` promotes `char`s (signed in my implementation), but due to 2's complement representation of `int`s, fails to retrieve the absolute value of INT_MIN.

Comment: This would be even better if you use SFINAE, so that types that can't​ promote to unsigned long long also work