# Verify floating point representation

Tags: floating-point, binary, logic, precision, feature-engineering

I want to encode -(263.125) in base 10.
I encoded it and arrived at this solution :

```
11000011110000011100100000000000
```

I just want to make sure that it is correct.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. After which guidelines/algorithm did you convert the number?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, assuming you're trying to convert to a 32-bit IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point number. The encoding you found corresponds to:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 1 10000111 10000011100100000000000
             Hex: C3C1 C800
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Negative
        Exponent: 8 (Stored: 135, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: -0x1.839p8
           Value: -387.5625 (NORMAL)
```

The correct encoding for `-263.125` as a single-precision float is:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 1 10000111 00000111001000000000000
             Hex: C383 9000
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Negative
        Exponent: 8 (Stored: 135, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: -0x1.072p8
           Value: -263.125 (NORMAL)
```

So, you got the sign and the exponent correct; but your fraction is not quite right.

Comment: But when you convert "263" into a binary number and to base 2, at the end of the division you will have a "1".

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused by the "implicit 1"?  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930269/floating-point-the-leading-1-is-implicit-in-the-significand-huh