# CSAPP 3ed Practice Problem 2.49 IEEE Floating-Point Precision

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

> For a ﬂoating-point format with an n-bit fraction, give a formula for
> the smallest positive integer that cannot be represented exactly
> (because it would require an (n + 1)-bit fraction to be exact). Assume
> the exponent ﬁeld size k is large enough that the range of
> representable exponents does not provide a limitation for this
> problem.

The solution given by the book is 2^(n + 1) + 1, but it doesn't provide any explanations. Could some explain how we derive this formula? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Consider a number written in binary. If the distance from its first 1 bit to its last 1 bit is n−1 bits or less, then those two bits and all the bits between them fit in n bits.  They may be followed by zeros, but the floating-point format can add zeros after a number by increasing the exponent. What is the smallest integer for which the non-zero bits do not fit in n bits? If you have trouble answering that, try it with n=3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a [32-bit floating-point IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) representation which has a **23**-bit precision fraction.

The 24-bit integer 111111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>24</sup> - 1 can be represented exactly, because there are enough bits (even if the most significant one is [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930269/floating-point-the-leading-1-is-implicit-in-the-significand-huh)).

Adding 1, we have 1000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>24</sup>. No problem with that, even if it's 25-bit number, because it's a power of two.

The next one, 1000000000000000000000001<sub>2</sub> = **2<sup>24</sup> + 1**, though, can't be exactly represented because there aren't enough bits in fraction part of the representation.